# Ways to share i18n locales between multiple javascript projects

Tags: javascript, react-native, vue.js, internationalization

I need to share the same i18n translation files between two applications, one web application in Vue and one mobile application in React Native. Both applications are under different git repository.

I could try to share it with a monorepo configuration or with third npm package with only translations used as dependency.

What are the common ways to handle the same translation files in multiple javascript projects?

Comment: I would probably not use a dedicated npm-package, but a "Git Submodule". "Git Submodules" have the advantage that they are easy to modify for everyone, without needing to manage a publishing-key for an npm organization.
Moreover, I recommend to use a tool like "attranslate" to synchronize translation-files: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate